# Adding parentheses yielding different results in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I created two SQL statements and the second is giving much less results. The only difference is I added additional parentheses to the second query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM records
JOIN other_records ON records.other_record_id = other_records.id
WHERE other_records.practice = 'Medical' && 
records.details IS NULL || 
(records.details <> 'ERROR' && records.details <> 'ERROR BY PRACTICE');

+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   342668 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3.42 sec)

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records JOIN other_records 
ON records.other_record_id = other_records.id 
WHERE other_records.practice = 'Medical' && 
(records.details IS NULL || (records.details <> 'ERROR' && records.details <> 'ERROR BY PRACTICE'));

+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   193899 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.46 sec)
```

As far as I understand, first it will match the result of the JOIN with other_records.practice is Medical. Both should return the same result set at this point. Then as I understand, it will match either where details is null or where details do not match ERROR and ERROR BY PRACTICE. I am not sure why parentheses are making a difference here?

Comment: `A && (B || C)` is different from `A && B || C` since `||` operator has lower precedence

Comment: "first it will match the result" --- SQL does not imply order of expression evaluation, it's a declarative language: the result must comply with predicates. You specify _what_ not _how_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In boolean logic the **and** operator `&&` takes precedence over the **or** operator `||`.

So, when you write this:

```
WHERE other_records.practice = 'Medical' && 
records.details IS NULL ||
(records.details <> 'ERROR' && records.details <> 'ERROR BY PRACTICE')
```

...it is equivalent to this:

```
WHERE (other_records.practice = 'Medical' && records.details IS NULL)
||
(records.details <> 'ERROR' && records.details <> 'ERROR BY PRACTICE')
```

...hence the different results to your second statement.

Comment: Now it makes sense because:

WHERE (other_records.practice = 'Medical' && records.details IS NULL)
||
(records.details <> 'ERROR' && records.details <> 'ERROR BY PRACTICE')

Is not what I would want. This would return practices that are not just Medical!